# Incorrect output : Binary Search Tree implementation using Java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am new to Java and I have been trying to implement a BST but the program outputs only the last inserted value. Am I going wrong with respect to what my `root_node` is pointing at? Below are my source codes for `Tree.java` and `Node.java`.

**Tree.java**

```
public class Tree {

    private Node root_node;

    public void Tree() {
        this.root_node = null;
    }

    public void insertNode (int value) {

        root_node = insertNode(root_node, value);
    }

    public Node insertNode (Node node, int insert_value) {

        if (node == null) {
            return (new Node(insert_value));
        }
        else {
            if (node.getNodeValue() < insert_value)
                node = insertNode(node.getLeftNode(), insert_value);
            else
                node = insertNode(node.getRightNode(), insert_value);

            return (node);
        }
    }

    public void printNode () {

        printNode(root_node);
    }

    public void printNode (Node node) {

        if (node != null){

            System.out.print(node.getNodeValue() + " ");

            printNode(node.getLeftNode());
            printNode(node.getRightNode());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Tree tree = new Tree();

        tree.insertNode(54);
        tree.insertNode(87);
        tree.insertNode(11);
        tree.insertNode(25);

        tree.printNode();
    }
}
```

**Node.java**

```
public class Node {

    private int node_value;

    private Node left_node, right_node;

    public Node(int root_value) {

        this.node_value = root_value;

        this.left_node = null;
        this.right_node = null;

    }

    public int getNodeValue() { return (this.node_value); }

    public Node getLeftNode() { return (this.left_node); }

    public Node getRightNode() { return (this.right_node); }
}
```

The error is that my source code only displays the last inserted no. which is 25 in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation of `insertNode` is incorrect.
You always call this method with:

> ```
> root_node = insertNode(root_node, value);
> ```

And then if you look at the method:

> ```
> if (node == null) {
>     return (new Node(insert_value));
> }
> else {
>     if (node.getNodeValue() < insert_value)
>         node = insertNode(node.getLeftNode(), insert_value);
>     else
>         node = insertNode(node.getRightNode(), insert_value);
>
>     return (node);
> }
> ```

On the first call, the first `if` condition will match,
a new node will be created and assigned to `root_node` in the caller.

But then,
in subsequent calls, what will happen?
The first `if` doesn't match, so the `else` block will be taken.
But then,
both branches reassign the *`node` parameter of the method*.
So the effects of the `else` method will remain inside the `insertNode` method, and so no other value will ever be added.

Aside from rewriting the `insertNode` method,
you will need other changes too.
For example,
currently there is no way to set or modify the left and right nodes of a node.
You will need to add some way for that, either by setters or constructors.

For example, with appropriate setters added, this will work:

```
  public Node insertNode(Node node, int insert_value) {
    if (node == null) {
      return new Node(insert_value);
    }
    if (node.getNodeValue() < insert_value) {
      node.setLeftNode(insertNode(node.getLeftNode(), insert_value));
    } else {
      node.setRightNode(insertNode(node.getRightNode(), insert_value));
    }
    return node;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you - great answer!. What I did was to make left_node and right_node public and use initialization instead of setting it through a method in the if loop. @janos

Answer (score 1):

What seems to happen is that this errors out:

You create your `root_node` with the first call (should be called `rootNode` following java conventions).
Then you call either getLeftNode or getRightNode, but those do not exist, so I guess they return `null`.

```
        if (node.getNodeValue() < insert_value)
            node = insertNode(node.getLeftNode(), insert_value);
        else
            node = insertNode(node.getRightNode(), insert_value);
```

returns null on the second call.

Now your `root_node` is null again, with as result that you only have the last inserted value, etc. So this seems to be the reason why your code only returns the last node value when you call print.

Answer (score 1):

In you `Tree` class ,the mehtod `public Node insertNode (Node node, int insert_value)` is not correctly,shoude like this:

```
        if (node.getNodeValue() < insert_value) {
            Node left = insertNode(node.getLeftNode(), insert_value);
            node.left_node = left;
        }

        else {
            Node right = insertNode(node.getRightNode(), insert_value);
            node.right_node=right;
        }
```

you should save the new node which return by the `insertNode` into leftchild node field or rightchild node field in which current node,if not,the `printNode` will just print `root` node and return,because the `root` node's left or right child node is `null`.